# What is the best pattern for hiding immutable property backed by mutable data and also support for collection KVO-compliant in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties, key-value-observing

I have a class that's have the property which is array backed by the mutable one. If I want this property to be KVO-compliant, What is the best pattern for this?

Is the following code KVO-compliant on property data?

```
@interface Store : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSArray *data;
@end

@interface Store ()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *storeData;
@end

@implementation Store
- (NSArray *)data {
  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.storeData];
}

@end
```

How to make the data property be the collection KVO-compliant? Now I (with help of Aaron Brager) can think of 2 options

First is do the manual posting.
Second is use the mutable collection KVC method (eg. `mutableArrayValueForKey:`)

Or are there other ways to do this?

The second choice require less code but cannot prevent other objects to mutate the data property.

Which way do you prefer?

Comment: If you implement `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`, what will you need to do manually?

Comment: What you're talking about is called "Dependent Keys" and the different approaches you can take are basically all outlined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html

Comment: I mean I have to do manual KVO notification or use the `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey` or other ways?

Comment: Yep the "Dependent Keys" is one of the way to do but I want to know if there are better ways for this.

Comment: And I don't sure if the Dependent Keys support for the collection KVO eg. `Change:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the following code KVO-compliant on property data?

No.  A notification will not be generated for the key path "data" if `storeData` is modified.

This is a "To-One" relationship as outlined in [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide: Registering Dependent Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html)

Therefore, you should add:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingData {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"storeData", nil];
}
```

Also, note that only *changing* `storeData` will cause a notification.  Adding or removing objects to/from a mutable array will *not* cause a notification.  If you want to do this, either manually post a change notification when you add or remove objects to `storeData`, or use `self.storeData = [self.storeData mutableCopy]` when you're done with your changes.

Comment: Does the `keyPathsForValuesAffectingData` way also post the collection KVO notifications? If no, are there the way to support that?

Comment: I see. So I have 2 options
First is do the manual posting
Second is use the mutable collection KVC method (eg. `mutableArrayValueForKey:` which require less code but other objects can also mutate the data property
Which one do you prefer? Or are there other way?